# Remove Specified Item. Here's my question what happens when have 2 same items in list, why only one is removed? why both can't be removed? in python

Tags: python, list

Here's my code, What i wanted to do is completely remove 'banana' from list.
**CODE**

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "banana"]
thislist.remove("banana")
print(thislist)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['apple', 'cherry', 'banana']
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html: "*list.remove(x): Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x.*"

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
thislist = [item for item in thislist if item != "banana"]
```